# Ionic 6 + Vuejs 3 - routes guards called before initialisation logic

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3

Using Ionic and Vuejs, I find myself struggling to achieve initialisation logic in my application.

I have guards that will allow or not navigation inside of a component. Let's say it's to handle login. Those guards need to know if I'm logged in or not.

But here is the catch : guards are called before anything else ! See the following code  from main.ts

```
const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp(App).use(IonicVue).use(pinia).use(router);

const appStore = useAppStore();
appStore.init().then(() => {
  console.log("app store init");
  router.isReady().then(() => {
    app.mount("#app");
  });
});
```

The guards registered in my router are called before the appStore.init() function resolve.

The exact same code using only a vuejs application works properly, meaning the init function is called and resolved before any routes guards.

It's probably a Ionic specific behavior, and I should find an other place to initialize my application maybe ?

Thanks a lot for reading and helping, have a nice day !